# Adding Customer records via Liquid?

Tags: shopify, liquid

Basically, I'm looking for the absolute simplest way to add an email (which is effectively a Customer object with no other parameters) to my list of Customers. The use-case is a jQuery-based pop-up email collector that I'm writing because I'm not happy with/don't want to pay for more established solutions.

Everything is working correctly, except I'm stuck on how exactly to authenticate to my Shopify store. Via Javascript I can only perform a few API calls, none of which I need. There are also very complex solutions for creating full-fledged apps for Shopify which are able to do everything, but I think that's overkill for this one API request I need to make.

I know that all I need to do is make a POST request once authenticated [per these instructions](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/customer#create). What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create user from jQuery you can generate using AJAX POST call in appropriate URL generated using [Private App](https://help.shopify.com/api/getting-started/authentication/private-authentication), but be careful before placing authorization details in front end since it will be visible and any one can misuse it.
The better way is to create user using HTTP Post call from some server side language like JAVA or PhP or some language.